# remove context attribute from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have many objects that store object in context
after use that variable that store their value.
After some processing I want to remove that object from the context.

For example:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
boolean chk;
chk=true;

// save that value in context attribute
context.setAttribute("myArray",chk);

// after it used no need to require that object 
//  so how can I remove that object from the context?
if(somecondition){
// I want to remove myArray attribute from context
}
```

So how can  perform that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ServletContext#removeAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#removeAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method to remove attribute.

For safety check attribute is set or not using `getAttribute()` method.

```
if(somecondition){
   //i wnat to remove myArray attribute form contect
   if(context.getAttribute("myArray") != null) {
     context.removeAttribute("myArray");
   }
}
```

---

> **void removeAttribute(java.lang.String name)**
>
> - Removes the attribute with the given name from this `ServletContext`.
> - After removal, subsequent calls to `getAttribute(java.lang.String)` to retrieve the attribute's value will return `null`.
> - If listeners are configured on the `ServletContext` the container notifies them accordingly.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - name - a String specifying the name of the attribute to be removed

Answer (score 0):

public abstract void removeAttribute(String name)

Removes the attribute from the context that is bound to a particular name.

so do some thing like below

```
context.removeAttribute("myArray");
```